# XAML / cs - member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type (CS0542) after updating packages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just updated packages in my application and I am getting many new errors of this type that I don't understand:

```
/Users/alan/Downloads/Japanese 31/Japanese/obj/Debug/Views/Help/GettingStarted.xaml.g.cs(51,51): 

Error CS0542: 'GettingStarted': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type (CS0542) (Japanese)
```

I have XAML code that looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"
    x:Class="Japanese.GettingStarted"
    x:Name="GettingStarted" 
    Title="Getting Started">
<ContentPage.Content>
```

My C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class GettingStarted : ContentPage
    {
        public GettingStarted()
        {
```

Am I coding my XAML and cs wrongly? I thought this is the way to do this with partial classes and the same class name.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`x:Name="GettingStarted"` this is the problem. This will be the name of your page, but it is also the name of the class of that page. Specifying a value for the `x:Name` attribute creates a variable with that name in your code-behind. So what you'll get is: `GettingStarted GettingStarted = new GettingStarted();` This is confusing to say the least. I'm guessing the Xamarin team ran into a problem with these identical names and types and decided to block it.

Try coming up with a different name, or, if you don't want to use a different casing like: `x:Name="gettingStarted"`

Comment: Hi Gerald - This seemed to bite me after updating Xamarin Forms nuget - thanks for the solution.

Comment: Glad it helped yet another person! :)

Comment: Helped me also, Thanks @GeraldVersluis

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too. In my case, I just deleted the `X:Name="class"` declaration

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while trying to Rename the Class file of the XAML in *.xaml.cs

Simple fix I had found:

1. Copy all the text/script inside *.xaml & *.xaml.cs
2. Delete the WPF window/usercontrol
3. Create new WPF window/usercontrol with the new name as you like
4. Paste the copied *.xaml & *.xaml.cs (change the name of class file after pasting)
5. Now it should work like charm