# member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type in xaml.g.cs

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Updated my xamarin.forms nuget package from 3.0.53 to 3.5.0 (Yes I skipped a lot of versions). But now I get the following error in some of my xaml.g.cs files

```
CS0542: 'LocationsView': member names cannot be the sam as their enclosing type
```

I know you can change the name of the variable by changing the x:Name field in the xaml file which the xaml.g.cs is generated from as demonstrated in the following link. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129503/after-upgrading-xamarin-forms-from-version-3-0-0-561731-to-3-1-0-583944-i-get-a-compile-error

Sadly this does not work for me because then the FindByName method in the xaml.g.cs won't work because the name doesn't match the name of the class it's trying to find. This really sucks because it does not work in both ways.

Part of my xaml.g.cs file:

```
[global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("Views\\Location\\LocationsView.xaml")]
public partial class LocationsView : global::Views.UserControls.RootPage {

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
    private global::Views.UserControls.RootPage LocationsView;

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(LocationsView));
        LocationsView = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Views.UserControls.RootPage>(this, "LocationsView");
    }
}
```

Part of my xaml file:

```
<UserControls:RootPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="Driessen.MijnDriessen.Views.DriessenLocationsView"
                     xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:Xam.Behaviors;assembly=Xam.Behaviors"
                     xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.UserControls;assembly=MyApp"
                     xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views;assembly=MyApp"
                     xmlns:AppFramework="clr-namespace:AppFramework;assembly=AppFramework"
                     x:Name="LocationsView"
                     AutomationId="LocationsView"
                     Title="Locaties">
```

Is there a way to work around the CS50542 Error so that the FindByName method can still give me a valid output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAML / cs - member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type (CS0542) after updating packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210658/xaml-cs-member-names-cannot-be-the-same-as-their-enclosing-type-cs0542-aft)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, The answer of that question does not solve my problem as shown in my question with the given URL which suggests a simmilar solution

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to do here. When you change the name, the xaml.g.cs updates accordingly. The g stands for generated. If you are doing things in there manually, that is a problem in itself.

Comment: Why not change it back build it once and then re-change and try building?

Comment: Somewhere in xamarin forms 3.1 a change has been made that the names in the generated file are not allowed to be the same as the name of the class you are trying the find. When hanging the X:name field in the xaml file it generates different and the names won't be the same. But this also means that the class can not be found because it;s trying to look for another name

Comment: This link describes more of the problem https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3136#issuecomment-399898809

Comment: So that answered your issue?

Comment: No because I still get errors

Comment: what are those?

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. The `xaml.g.cs` is generated based on your xaml file. If you change the name in your XAML file, this will also change in your `xaml.g.cs` file. I'm not sure if I understand what your problem is.

Comment: Well if I change the name in my xaml file, then most of my test will fail with an invalidOperationException because the my class can't be found in the xaml.g.cs file.

Comment: OK, that seems to be a different problem. Try renaming and clean/build the project, maybe manually delete the obj and bin folders from your project and see if that helps.

Comment: According to your generated files, you have `Views\\Location\\LocationsView.xaml`, which suggests you've created a class called `LocationsView`. You have also given your page `x:Name="LocationsView"` (as seen in the generated file). This will confuse the compiler, as one is a class name and the other is a variable name. Have you tried changing either of these?

Comment: after updating XF, delete obj/bin folders to let VS regenerate the g.cs files

Comment: Does this problem has been solved?